# Problema em ordenação de array com valores numéricos em VUE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho o código abaixo em que estou utilizando para ordenar um array, em campo com o formato String está funcionando normalmente, como devo fazer para ordenar campo numérico?

```
list_cob_frequencia() {
    var campo = 'nome_campo';
    var ordem = 'ASC';
    return this.json_cobertura_frequencia.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
        if (ordem == 'ASC') {
            return (a[campo] < b[campo]) ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return (b[campo] < a[campo]) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Deu certo alguma resposta ?

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar número o exemplo abaixo já esclarece a sua duvida:

```js
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
document.getElementById("demoO").innerHTML = points;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<hr />
<div id="demoO"></div>
```

No seu código algo assim:

```
list_cob_frequencia() {
    var campo = 'nome_campo';
    var ordem = 'ASC';   
    return this.json_cobertura_frequencia.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
        if (ordem == 'ASC') {
            return (a[campo] - b[campo]);
        } else {
            return (b[campo] - a[campo]);
        }
    });
}
```

***Observação:*** o campo a ser feito a operação deve ser um número e se precisar de alguma conversão utilize [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

<sup>***Referencia:*** [JavaScript Array sort() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)</sup>